# cleveref Error:! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: pdftex

If I use cleveref tool, I get the following error:

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

To totally understand the issue, I give you **complete original tex code**: as:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}


%
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}                 % onecolumn (standard format)
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boldsymbol macro
\usepackage{bm}      % for \bm macro
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow,caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\title{12234}

\author{abcde}

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{Zasdasdas    %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
1232445345
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

%%%
12312343
%%%
\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `svjour3` class uses a low level command, which breaks with newer versions of the LaTeX kernel.

You can solve the issue by calling the class with the `envcountsect` option. I'm afraid that without updating the class there is no sensible way to fix the problem.

```
\documentclass[
  smallextended,
  envcountsect,
]{svjour3} % onecolumn (standard format)
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\begin{document}

\title{12234}

\author{abcde}

\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{Zasdasdas    %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
1232445345
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

%%%
12312343
%%%
\end{document}
```

I removed all packages that are unnecessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: it is now solved!